# How to logout / signout from IBM Cloud App ID in Python Flask

Tags: python, security, flask, ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I have integrated IBM Cloud App ID service in my Python Flask web application referring this [link](https://github.com/mnsn/appid-python-flask-example)

The login is working through Google/Facebook but I am not able to logout from the application.

Does anyone know how to logout from this application?

Answer (score 0):

That Python app is using [Flask and its `session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions) to manage the authorization scope and tokens. You could implement a route `logout` that removes the stored information from `session`. Parts of it are already shown for invalid authorization requests in your linked sample:

```
if (not idTokenPayload or not accessTokenPayload):
            session[WebAppStrategy['AUTH_CONTEXT']]=None
```